# java web application deployed on application server

Tags: java, server

My application is working fine on apache Tomcat 7.0. But when i am deploying it on WebSphere Application Server, it is giving status error 500 and in logs, it is giving:

```
[10/22/15 11:39:20:216 AST] 00000036 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[null]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport:
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:637)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1189)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:725)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:997)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:1079)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:999)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3954)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1656)
```

Comment: i am trying to deploy war file on application server. It is rendering welcome page but when i am logging using username and password it is giving status error 500

Comment: did you follow the advice here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/WebSphere, about adding custom properties?